# Android AOSP build image and its dependency on vendor code

Tags: linux, build, android-source

I have built a Android 10 AOSP image successfully. I understand that some vendor specific code needs to be integrated with AOSP to make a successful boot.

But, I have no clue to how to integrate it. Please some one comment on this or point me to some info link.

Below are few of my other questions:

1. Linux uses `dtb` files which has info about board and SOC how this is handled in android is it same?
2. As different SOC's have different IP implementations related to peripherals ideally kernel also should have specific drivers related to same but how these will be supported in kernel of either android/linux.
3. On my mobile vendor website i can see source code is available for kernel can I use it along with AOSP the no need of DTB's?

Answer (score 0):

Android only requires your kernel to have a certain set of configurations (e.g. Binder support). Other than that the kernel and the whole boot process that comes before `init` is started in user-space is considered vendor responsibility, because it is hardware dependent.